# subversion per module add,copy,modify,delete notification

Tags: svn, post-commit, commit-message

Currently I have a mailer.py file that sends an email when there is a commit on a particular repository. 


Anyone knows how to have ONLY emails sent out to the owner of modules (directories) within a repository?

Example:

http://sigserver/sigrepo1 (everyone gets an email for any commit on this repo1)


http://sigserver/sigrepo1/mymodule (I need to only be notified if mymodule changes)


In CVS, there is a cvsinfo file that takes care of this, I am wondering if SVN has such a thing

Comment: Seems to be a good question for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to cvsinfo, however you can use a **post-commit hook** script(written in your favorite language) to examine the revision and sent notifications according to the modified paths.

To retrieve the modified actions use the svnlook command:

```
svnlook changed -r REV REPO_PATH
```

Note that Revision (REV) and path to repo (REPO_PATH) are both arguments provided by subversion through post-commit-call